# Javafx Application with multiple windows for 2 different users . error Not on FX application thread;

Tags: java, javafx

I'm building a Java standalone application, with two different GUI used by two different users  . I want two different threads ,each thread has to manage one GUI.
I have the error

> Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4

How can I solve it ?

```
package kapta.classes;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import kapta.classes.Utils.ThreadLocalSession;

import java.io.IOException;

 public class MainApp extends Application {

  @Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("here main");
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(MainApp.class.getResource("Login.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
    stage.setTitle("Mate");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    //stage.setFullScreen(true);
    stage.show();

    ThreadLocalSession firstUser = new ThreadLocalSession();
    new Thread(firstUser).start();

}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}


}
```

In the class ThreadLocalSession ==>

```
   package kapta.classes.Utils;


public class ThreadLocalSession implements Runnable
{

private static ThreadLocal<Session> userSession;
private String username;


public ThreadLocalSession(){}
public ThreadLocalSession(String username){
    this.username = username;
    this.userSession = new ThreadLocal<>();
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public static void setUserSession(ThreadLocal<Session> userSession) {
    ThreadLocalSession.userSession = userSession;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public static ThreadLocal<Session> getUserSession() {
    return userSession;
}


@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("1");

    try {
        Platform.runLater(display());
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

private Runnable display() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println("trd");
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(MainApp.class.getResource("Login.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
    stage.setTitle("New");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.showAndWait();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The `ThreadLocalSession` class does not appear to be extending `Application` or creating a new instance of the `MainApp` class so you can not run an FX application from it. For all intents and purposes you should be creating two separate FX applications, that just happen to be started from within the same project.

Comment: Is your goal to open two separate windows within the same app?

Comment: `Platform.runLater(() -> display());`, not `Platform.runLater(display());` and you should not `sleep` in there.

Comment: yes i have to open two  separate windows within the same app when it start @BasilBourque

Comment: display() can be a procedure, give it a void return type, it does not need to return anything, especially not null.

Comment: “I want two different threads ,each thread has to manage one GUI” -> no, you cannot do that.  Each VM can only have a  single JavaFX application thread to manage the GUI.  See [javafx architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#A1106308).  While the comments and answers here address the obvious error with the code provided, I think your overall strategy is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstood how to pass a Runnable object to a method like Platform.runLater.

Your `display()` method is not creating a Runnable at all.  In fact, it always returns null!  Therefore, you are not passing a Runnable to Platform.runLater at all.

Instead, `display()` is *immediately executing* all of your JavaFX code.  In other words, this line:

```
Platform.runLater(display());
```

is exactly equivalent to this:

```
Runnable task = display();
Platform.runLater(task);
```

Ask you can see, `display()` has fully executed *before* Platform.runLater is called!  So it’s not actually being run later at all.  This is the cause of the exception you’re seeing:  You are running code in `ThreadLocalSession.run()` itself, not in the JavaFX platform thread.

Also, the `display()` method in its current form is not suitable for running in the JavaFX platform thread, because Thread.sleep calls are not allowed in that thread.  The compiler won’t detect it and runtime can’t stop you from doing it, but doing so will cause all event processing to be suspended for the duration of the sleep.  During that time, no nodes will be painted, no user input will be recognized, and no windows will appear.

What you want to do is call Thread.sleep from your `run()` method, then return a Runnable containing all of the remaining code:

```
private Runnable display() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // This method is called from ThreadLocalSession.run(), so
    // we are not in the JavaFX platform thread.
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    Runnable displayer = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("trd");
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(MainApp.class.getResource("Login.fxml"));
            try {
                Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
                stage.setTitle("New");
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.showAndWait();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
            }
        }
    };

    return displayer;
}
```

(You can also write a lambda to represent a Runnable, but I chose to use the explicit syntax for clarity.)

The run() method of Runnable is not allowed to throw checked exceptions like IOException, which is why IOException needs to caught inside that method.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a Runnable to runLater method, what happens is that you are returning null to runLater from display method as Runnable while the actual new window creation is still happening in the thread that is calling display method which causes the exception.
Try to pass a Runnable to runLater:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("1");
    Platform.runLater(()->{
      System.out.println("trd");
      Stage stage = new Stage();
      FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(MainApp.class.getResource("Login.fxml"));
      Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
      stage.setTitle("New");
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.showAndWait();
    });
}

// or Platform.runLater(()->display())
/* or in the old fashion: 
   Platform.runLater(new Runnable{
         @override
         public void run(){ display(); }
   });
*/
```